# How to batch export all UV layouts for multiple objects?

Tags: python, export, add-on, uv-image-editor

I'd like to export UV sets for several objects which I need to be separated. Imagine one layer per object on a PSD file... right now im exporting the maps one by one but would like to *try* writing a script to at least do this in batch.

I've tried the [answer by @HikariTW](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/139659/31447) and the code almost works, but not properly. I've managed to solve a few errors, but the script is not working as intended.

It gets the active object, adds another one from the list and saves *both* objects UV's. Ideally the script should set one object from one collection to active, set it to *Edit Mode*, export it's uv map using the object name as the image name, set it back to *Object Mode*, select next and iterate.

I've tried to write the code I need from scratch using the suggested one as a reference but it's way over me:

```
import bpy
import os

# You should change this varibale in "here" to match your own directory path
# use '/' or '\\' for hirecacy
target_dir = "D:/directory/" 

selObj = []

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
 selObj.append(obj.name)

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='TOGGLE')

i=0
while i < len(selObj):
#line 18 does not work (AttributeError: bpy_prop_collection: attribute "active" not found) so i've updated it to 19-20
    #bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.context.scene.objects[selObj[i]]
    obj = bpy.context.window.scene.objects[0]
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='TOGGLE')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='TOGGLE')
#no need for line 25 since objects have already been unwrapped    
    #bpy.ops.uv.smart_project(angle_limit=66.0, island_margin=0.0, user_area_weight=0.0)
    full_file_name=target_dir + bpy.data.objects[selObj[i]].name

    # This code detected whether target_dir exist, if not, then create it
    dirname = os.path.dirname(full_file_name)
    if not os.path.exists(dirname):
        os.makedirs(dirname)

    bpy.ops.uv.export_layout(filepath=full_file_name, mode='PNG', size=(1024, 1024), opacity=0.6)
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='TOGGLE')
    i+=1
```

**Q:** How can I make that work to export the maps for all objects?

Comment: Welcome Rodrigo! Sure, that's possible. What *exactly* you can not access? I guess you'd like to get the python tooltips right? Go to 'User Preferences > Interface' and enable 'python tooltips' as well as 'Developer Extras'. Also, it seems there already is an answer to this over here: [Python: How to Export All the UV Layouts in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139659/python-how-to-export-all-the-uv-layouts-in-blender). Suggest try the script and report back by editing your question, please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask